# "Matplotlib does not support generators as input. When i try to plot list with scatter() "

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_values = list(range(1,1001))
y_values = (x**2 for x in x_values)
plt.scatter(x_values,y_values,s=10)
#range of axis
plt.axis([0,1100,0,1100000])
plt.show()
```

Whenever i try to plot a list of numbers through scatter method in python, I always get the error that "matplotlib does not support generatore". Is there any solution?

---

[image: Image of code]

Comment: Can you show some simple sample code?

Comment: i have uploaded.

Comment: oh sorry !
here is the code bro :
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x_values = list(range(1,1001))
y_values = (x**2 for x in x_values)
plt.scatter(x_values ,y_values,s=10)
#range of axis
plt.axis([0,1100,0,1100000])
plt.show()

Comment: @AliIftikhar you should edit the question post to add your code and replace the link to the image.

Comment: @Ali I [edit]ed your question for you and pasted the code. Next time, please edit your source yourself.

Comment: You can plot your function even simpler by using `x = plt.linspace(0, 100, num=20)` and `y = x**2`.

Answer (score 1):

By doing

```
y_values = (x**2 for x in x_values)
```

you create a generator.

Make it a list and feed that:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_values = list(range(1,1001)) 
y_values = [x**2 for x in x_values]   # list - not generator
plt.scatter(x_values,y_values,s=10)

plt.axis([0,1100,0,1100000])
plt.show()
```

to get

[image: graph]

See:

- [Understanding generators in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756096/understanding-generators-in-python)